# Debian: jessie / sid

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

Perhaps a silly question but does the following mean I'm running sid? What is returned when you are running jessie non-sid? This happens to be on a beaglebone device. I'm asking because I'm working on a new project and I'm concerned that our devices have an 'unstable' version of Debian.

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
jessie/sid
```